# axShockwaveFlash_FSCommand not responding on some machines

Tags: c#, flash, installation

I have created a C sharp project in which i have added a ShockwaveFlashObject to play my swf file. 
The problem i am facing is when i create an installer for my project it works correctly on my machine on installation, but on my laptop the swf loads correctly but doesn't respond to the _FSCommand. I cannot use a try and catch block as it is not entering the FSCommand handle. Do i need to bundle something with my installation?
The laptop i am using is brand new and i wanted it that way so that i know what all stuff is needed for things to work correctly so that i can add prerequisites to my installer.
Also idk if this information is of any use but I am using advanced installer to build and exe for my project.

PS i have added things like the below code to know if FSCommand gets executed.

```
MessageBox.Show("step 1/2/3");
```

Here is the entire code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class frmFlashIntro : Form
    { 
      public Form FormfrmMainRef { get; set; }

        public frmFlashIntro()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            axShockwaveFlash1.Playing = true;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            string currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "file://\\" + currentPath + "\\intro.swf"; 
         }

         private void axShockwaveFlash1_FSCommand(object sender, AxShockwaveFlashObjects._IShockwaveFlashEvents_FSCommandEvent e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("step 1");
            string btn = e.command.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("step 2");
            if (btn == "play")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("step 3");
                try
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("step 4");
                    var form2 = new frmMain();
                    MessageBox.Show("step 5");
                    this.Hide();
                    MessageBox.Show("step 6");
                    form2.Show();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
            }
            if (btn == "syllabus")
            {
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.conString);
                con.Open();
                Syllabus_usageInformation syl = new Syllabus_usageInformation(this);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ImageFiles FROM misc WHERE id=1", con);
                byte[] img = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                string strFn = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFn, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
                fs.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();
                con.Close();
                syl.kpImageViewer1.OpenButton = false;
                syl.kpImageViewer1.ImagePath = strFn;
                syl.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            if (btn == "usageInformation")
            {   }
        }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is flash player ActiveX control installed on your laptop? You have to install it, otherwise there's nothing that can play your .swf file.

Comment: Do you mean that your function `axShockwaveFlash1_FSCommand` is not called?

Comment: i guess so. Because it works on one pc and doesnt on another. I tried installing it on another system with 7 installed and a few other too. it worked correctly on all 7 machines but didnt work on machines that use XP

Comment: I checked and found out that my code does not enter the asShockwaveFlash1_FSCommand(Object sender,(event args or something) e){} i found this because i had multiple ifs in that and no else so i added an else witha a msg box to it so that something still executes but it didnt execute that either hence i infer that FSCommand does not work at all in Xp